# angular2 - How to import LocalStorage

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular2-localstorage

So I'm a newbie to Angular2 and I've been trying to follow [this](https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/authentication-in-angular-2-958052c64492#.kimr8vbhw) tutorial for authentification

when I import localstorage I get this error in the code editor

[image]

I guess it has to be installed first right? But I couldn't figure out how to

thank you.

Comment: LocalStorage is part of the browser and not some library you need to import. Just use it.

Comment: yes it worked, nice, but why did they import it in the tutorial? that was necessary on a previous version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to import `localStorage`. you can use it directly.